# How to read pytest cmd configs from a non-fixture function

Tags: python, pytest

conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--env', action='store', default='qa',
                     help='setup environment: development')

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def get_config(request):
    
    environment = request.config.getoption("--env")
    with open(environment, "r") as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    return config
```

lib.py

```
class lib1():
    def cal_message():
        # get something from config, do something and return it, but how to get the config here
```

test_config.py

```
import lib
def test_lib():
    a = lib.lib1()
    a.cal_message()
```

The question is how to get config from lib.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom attribute to pytest and pass variables that way.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--env', action='store', default='qa',
                 help='setup environment: development')

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def get_config(request):
    environment = request.config.getoption("--env")
    pytest.custom_config = {"env":environment}
    with open(environment, "r") as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    return config
```

And, get it in lib.py:

```
import pytest
class lib1():
def cal_message():
    env = pytest.custom_config["env"]
```

A caveat: This will work only when lib.py is called from test module of a pytest test session. If you try using it in a standalone script, it won't work. e.g. `python lib.py --env a` will not work.